# Python replace and remove duplicate word in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace keyword and remove the duplicate words. But currently, I couldnt produce the result like I want. Here is my code :

```
words = 'AZ:ABC,AZ:DEF,AZ:GHI,AZ:ABC-OO'

words = words.replace('AZ:', '') 
words = words.replace(',', '\',\'')
words = words.replace('-OO', '')
words = '\'' + words + '\''

print(words )

totalBeforeCount = len(words)
print(totalBeforeCount)

filtering = list(set(words))
print(filtering)
print(len(filtering))
```

Below is my result I have currently :

[image]

So as you can see, instead it should remove one of `ABC`, it's actually separate them by alphabet.
My expected result should be : `'ABC','DEF'GHI'`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it looks like you are formatting it with the intent to pass it to `ast.literal_eval` although that'd be overkill, you probably want to just `list_of_words = words.split(",")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of trying to format the string to look like it has quotes around the commas, just use `.split(",")` to get back an actual list:

```
words = 'AZ:ABC,AZ:DEF,AZ:GHI,AZ:ABC-OO'
words = words.replace('AZ:', '') 
words = words.replace('-OO', '')
list_of_words = words.split(",")
print(list_of_words)
print(set(list_of_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using replace we can first split with respect to ":"  then split with respect to "," gives the expected result.

```
>> words.split(":")
>> ["'ABC','DEF','GHI','ABC'"]

>> words.split(":")[0].split(",")
>> ["'ABC'", "'DEF'", "'GHI'", "'ABC'"]
```

In one line

```
>> set(words.split(":")[0].split(","))
>> {"'ABC'", "'DEF'", "'GHI'"}
```